# Find and replace all numbers with 0?

Tags: substitute, number-formatting

Is there a command to find and replace all instances of a number in a file with 0 (including decimal numbers like `1.7`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Based on the help file, and the [Vim Wikia page on Search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace)

```
:%s/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\|[0-9]\+/0/g
```

`:%s` - start a command with the range of the entire file, `%`, to substitute, the following patterns:

```
[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+
```

This must come first, it's the pattern that covers decimals like 1.7. In addition it will only match a number followed by a period, without replacing the period. `[0-9]` is the collection for any digit. The `\` is required to escape the special characters, `+`, which means match one or more occurrences. The `.` needs to be escaped, so that it doesn't take on it's normal meaning of match any character.

`|` means or, as in match the first pattern or the second, and must be escaped.

Then the pattern for any digit, one or more times, `[0-9]\+` again.

```
/0/g
```

Finally, replace every occurrence of the pattern on the line with 0.

For example,

```
123
1.7
8
99
2.
```

becomes

```
0
0
0
0
0.
```

Comment: can simplify to `:%s/\v\d+(\.\d+)?/0/g`